# how to use onsubmit after ajax check

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

how to take onsubmit method after ajax check?
onsubmit is not working now

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#p_code").change(function(){
        $("#message").html("<img src='ajax_loader.gif' width='26px' height='26px' /> checking...");

        var data1 = $("#p_code").val();




    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'check.php',

        data: $('form').serialize(),



        success: function validate(data){


            if (data==1){
                $("#message").html("<img src='tick.png' />");
            $("#div2").css("visibility","visible");
            return true

                }


            else{
                $("#message").html("<img src='cross.png' />No matches Found");
        $("#div2").css("visibility","hidden");
            return false
        }



        }
    })

    });
});
```

form not working...

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()" action="run.php">
```

Comment: This will not do what you expect `success: function validate(data){`

Comment: Where is problem ,You are applying ajax check ,and if there is no data ,then You return false ,and submit doesnt happen,Where is problem

Comment: now i add $('form1').submit();
   return true on my code.
 
and form1: 

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="run.php"> and nothing happens submit button working any time

Answer (score 0):

use **[submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)**

apply  `$('form').submit();` after ajax success

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#p_code").change(function () {

    $("#message").html("<img src='ajax_loader.gif' width='26px' height='26px' /> checking...");

    var data1 = $("#p_code").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check.php',

        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function validate(data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $("#message").html("<img src='tick.png' />");
                $("#div2").css("visibility", "visible");
                $('form').submit(); //appy submit event here 

                return true

            } else {
                $("#message").html("<img src='cross.png' />No matches Found");
                $("#div2").css("visibility", "hidden");
                return false
            }



        }
    })

});
```

});

Comment: At least format the code? And there is no use for return false/true

Comment: use normal  $('form').submit();on ajax success

Comment: This code is good but.... if value is not in DB i can press submit button and go to run file if value exist in DB than im directed automatically..

Comment: I need block a submit button if value is not in DB and unblock if value in DB

Comment: How to transfer variable data to another function? if is is does not working i would like creat new function just for submit. Example i take data value from validate(data) and use on my new function? new function: function valid(){ var new= validate(date);

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(document).on('submit', '#form1', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});  
});


function validate()
{

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "check.php",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success:function(data){
        if(data=='authenticated')
            {
            window.location = "run.php";
            }
    }



});
}
```

Comment: when you click submit the validate function will be called which will do the ajax check once the check is done your submit action will be called which in your case is run.php

Comment: well if copy pasted the exact thing it might not work you need to change the if condition according to your need if not remove the condtion

success:function(data){
            window.location = "run.php";
    }